# How to get entity change delta in EF?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I need to get the list of changed fields only, the datastore is ssce so no triggers are available

Is there any support in EF to get a list or to build a generic component ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on the type of context and generated entities you can do it in several different ways.
In case of objects inherited from Entity or POCO you can use [`ObjectStateManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.objectstatemanager.aspx)
in case of Self-Tracking entities you can use Tracker from entity itself.

please provide more details on the way how you generated context and how you make changes

EDITED(2):
you can query `ObjectStateManager` for changed entries simply like this:

```
 var changed = ctx.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries().Where(e=>e.State != EntityState.Unchanged);
```

EDITED(1):

The following example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstateentry.aspx) demonstrate how to query for changes:

```
int orderId = 43680;

using (AdventureWorksEntities context =
new AdventureWorksEntities())
{
var order = (from o in context.SalesOrderHeaders
             where o.SalesOrderID == orderId
             select o).First();

// Get ObjectStateEntry from EntityKey.
ObjectStateEntry stateEntry =
    context.ObjectStateManager
    .GetObjectStateEntry(((IEntityWithKey)order).EntityKey);

//Get the current value of SalesOrderHeader.PurchaseOrderNumber.
CurrentValueRecord rec1 = stateEntry.CurrentValues;
string oldPurchaseOrderNumber =
    (string)rec1.GetValue(rec1.GetOrdinal("PurchaseOrderNumber"));

//Change the value.
order.PurchaseOrderNumber = "12345";
string newPurchaseOrderNumber =
    (string)rec1.GetValue(rec1.GetOrdinal("PurchaseOrderNumber"));

// Get the modified properties.
IEnumerable<string> modifiedFields = stateEntry.GetModifiedProperties();
foreach (string s in modifiedFields)
    Console.WriteLine("Modified field name: {0}\n Old Value: {1}\n New Value: {2}",
        s, oldPurchaseOrderNumber, newPurchaseOrderNumber);

// Get the Entity that is associated with this ObjectStateEntry.
SalesOrderHeader associatedEnity = (SalesOrderHeader)stateEntry.Entity;
Console.WriteLine("Associated Enity's ID: {0}", associatedEnity.SalesOrderID);
}
```

Comment: generated the model from db using the wizard, typical code repo.entity.value = newvalue to make changes

Comment: interesting, does it scale to multiple rows like if the "table" is bound to a grid & the user makes changes to a row but i don't know which one beforehand !! or do i need to get & store the ObjectStateEntry for each record in the list ( which could easily have > 10000 entries )

Comment: you can query `ObjectStateManager` for changes only

Comment: the other story is that in case of 10k entities loaded in memory you could use more sophisticated approaches to Entity Framework , i.e. load entities as detached, in OnChange handler attach entity to context which will create an entry in the context's `ObjectStateManager` and do not waste resources for state entries for whole 10k collection.

Comment: Also consider studying extensions available for Entity Framework such as Repository build up on top of it, as default generated context implement Unit Of Work pattern and implied to be used accordingly

Comment: thanks, will look into it, is there a best practices type "doc" for ef4.1 ? i have only come across some similar inquiries ( dated 2009 or before ) on google

Comment: just try to read msdn and this book http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596807252.do

Answer (score 2):

It's commonly a good practice to do this by using the database structure itself.
This is just another approach to the one you have now.

You can create a new field of type `datetime` in a table called for example `ModifiedOn` and update it every time that you update the row in the database.

Then when you want the changed rows after a specific time you just use:

```
where ModifiedOn > dateTime
```

It's just another suggestion on how you can approach the problem from a different angle.

Comment: in general you do not even need to manually update the field, there is dedicated field type for that - timestamp. this approach totally make sense but it only allow you to get the time of changes. you still need  to manually get the actual changes, what you can do just persisting original record together with new one or using more sophisticated approaches like quering log ( in SQL Server ).
On the other hand EntityFramework already hold this information prior to performing update to DB, so using this existing data is pretty obvious decision

Comment: @vittore - True. I totally agree with you. I just wanted to point out that for this particular problem there are other approaches.